# How to get access token from Authorisation Server using Apache Camel routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an authorization server [Simple Class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`,
`@RestController`,`@Configuration`,`@EnableAuthorizationServer` & oauth2 security] running on port `8081` which works fine & provides the access token when requested from POSTMAN using `POST` method along with needful parameters in the form of key value pair, 
`http://localhost:8080/oauth/token`, but how should i implement the camel route in java to get the access token by passing parameters in body ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is more about sending `multipart/form-data` with Apache Camel. I was playing with it some time ago and solved it with custom Processor, converting headers to `multipart/form-data` format with `Content-Disposition: form-data`.

**This is my Processor converting headers to `multipart/form-data` format:**

```
public class PrepareMultipartFormData implements Processor {
    private String[] multipartHeaders;

    public PrepareMultipartFormData(String... multipartHeaders) {
        this.multipartHeaders = multipartHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        addMultipart(exchange.getIn(), multipartHeaders);
    }

    private static void addMultipart(Message message, String... multipartKeys){
        final String boundary = "---------------------------"+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(9);
        message.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("--").append(boundary);

        for (String key: multipartKeys) {
                    sb.append("\r\n")
                    .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(key).append("\"")
                    .append("\r\n\r\n")
                    .append(message.getHeader(key, String.class))
                    .append("\r\n")
                    .append("--").append(boundary);
        }
        message.setBody(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

**To OAuth request token you need to send:**

- **HTTP headers**

  - Authorization header - This is part of standard [HTTP component](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) specified by endpoint options `authUsername` and `authPassword`
  - Content-Type - This is added in my `PrepareMultipartFormData` Processor
- **Form data** - These are converted from headers in `PrepareMultipartFormData` Processor

  - grant_type
  - username
  - password
  - client_id

**Final route can be implemented in this way:**
(Replace constants with some expressions, to set it dynamically. If you need only `token` in response, add some unmarshalling, since this route returns JSON)

```
from("direct:getTokenResponse")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, constant("oauth/token"))
        .setHeader("grant_type", constant("password"))
        .setHeader("username", constant("admin"))
        .setHeader("password", constant("admin1234"))
        .setHeader("client_id", constant("spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client"))
        .process(new PrepareMultipartFormData("grant_type", "username", "password", "client_id"))
        .to("http://localhost:8080?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=oauth-endpoint-username&authPassword=oauth-endpoint-password")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:response");
```

---

Updating answer to provide a bit shorter implementation of `PrepareMultipartFormData#addMultipart` using [MultipartEntityBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html).

```
private static void addMultipart(Message message, String... multipartKeys) throws Exception{
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    for (String key: multipartKeys) {
        builder.addTextBody(key, message.getHeader(key, String.class));
    }
    HttpEntity resultEntity = builder.build();
    message.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, resultEntity.getContentType().getValue());
    message.setBody(resultEntity.getContent());
}
```