# Apache Camel - Multipart File upload

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel, multipartform-data

Using Apache-Camel ESB, trying to upload a xlsx file to Spring Rest Web application. Upload fails from apache-camel ESB. But upload works fine from Postman. Shared code snippets below.

1. Processor Code in Router of Camel looks like

   ```
       from("file://data/PASInput").process(new Processor() {
       @Override
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

           MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
           multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
           String filename = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME);
           File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
           multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file",
               new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename));
           ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           multipartEntityBuilder.build().writeTo(out);
           InputStream  inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
           exchange.getOut().setBody(inputStream);         
       }
   }).to("http://localhost:8080/Pastel/api/convertor/pas/pastel")
           .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "RESPONSE BODY ${body}").end();
   ```
2. Pom.xml

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
           <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
           <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
           <version>2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
           <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
           <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
           <version>2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1</version>
       </dependency>       
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
           <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
           <version>2.17.2</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
3. Error

   ```
       org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8080/Pastel/api/convertor/pas/pastel with statusCode: 500
       at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:274)
      at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:183)
      at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
      at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:452)
      at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:219)
      at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:183)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   ```
4. When we hit the webservice using postman, there are no errors. Able to upload the servers successfully. Spring mvc code,

   ```
               @RequestMapping(value = "/pas/pastel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
               @ResponseBody
               public void convertPASToPastel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
               @RequestParam(value = "file") final MultipartFile pasFile) {
                  try {
                     System.out.print("Here");
                  }
               }
   ```

Comment: Set `Content-Type` in your processor. Have you seen my answer here? [Camel send multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925694/camel-send-multipart-form-data-request/50926452#50926452), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196703/how-to-get-access-token-from-authorisation-server-using-apache-camel-routes/50202765#50202765)?

Comment: Just a FYI there is no Apache-Camel ESB. Camel runs on Fuse, Service-Mix, Tomcat,WildFly or so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can probably see this error message in your Spring backend log:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request.

You need to set correct `ContentType` header. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925694/camel-send-multipart-form-data-request/50926452#50926452) similar question for solution, if you want to implement it in this way.

---

But you can get out this mess, if you switch co `camel-http4` component (you already have this component in pom.xml). This component contains logic for converting `HttpEntity` to `InputStream`. Then you can set `HttpEntity` directly to exchange body.

**Then your route will look something like this:**

```
from("file://data/PASInput").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
        File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
        multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file",
                new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename));
        exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
    }
}).to("http4://localhost:8080/Pastel/api/convertor/pas/pastel")
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "RESPONSE BODY ${body}").end();
```

---

And just a note. **Never mix component versions**, always use for components the same version as Apache Camel version. Otherwise you can see upredictable results. And why you have annotation `@ResponseBody` in Spring controller, when the method is `void`? You don`t need that.

Comment: This helped solving the issue. I changed to http4.

Comment: Note that http4 component is renamed in versios 3x and above. Check out [this link](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html)