# Camel 4 Multipart File upload

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, multipart

I created an application using Spring boot & apache camel. When I was on Camel 3.x I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218446/apache-camel-multipart-file-upload/51225444#51225444) to POST a file multipart/form-data file.
However since I've upgraded to Camel 4.0.0 it no longer works, when I now try to POST with this HttpEntity as the body I get this error:

```
No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity on: Message[xxx]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream. Exchange[xxx]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream]
```

From what I've been able to find the required converter was part of the deprecated http4 Camel 2 component. I also believed the main difference between camel-http (which replaced http4) version 3.x and 4.x is that they moved from HttpClient 4 to HttpClient 5. I've been trying various components (like httpmime & camel-mail) but to no avail.
Is there an existing component that will allow the conversion of a multipart http entity to an inputstream?

Comment: instead of InputStream looks like there is [FileBin](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientMultipartFormPost.java#L56) probably you have equivalent in camel.

Comment: As far as I know Camel requires an InputStream, the example you point too uses the same approach as what I'm doing. It uses a MultipartEntityBuilder. This seems to be the way to go with posting multipart files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, typical case of don't mix versions with Camel.
In the Camel 3 build I had the following dependency:

```
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14.redhat-00002</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is for the v4 HttpClient and that has the 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity' object. But the Camel 4 camel-http component has the HttpClinet v5 and that has a  org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity object. And guess what there is a converter to get from that to a InputStream.